# iOS 13 disable dark mode on Widget

Tags: ios, swift

I’ve successfully disabled dark mode on app using plist `UIUserInterfaceStyle` with key `Light`.

But. If I try to do the same for a widget, widget still appears in dark mode. I’ve also tried implement it in controller with `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light`. Nothing happens.

Somehow Google Maps Widget manages to be Light in Dark mode. So I see it’s possible.

Has anybody turned of dark mode for a widget?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: bear in mind: many apps' widget simply does not support dark-mode because they don't use iOS13 SDK yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to disable completely the dark mode on widget. What did I do was to changed the colors of the widget to better handle the UI and the UX.

In the widget view controller you have to handle the change to dark mode like this
`
    var isDarkMode = false

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)

    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        if (newCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark) {
            isDarkMode = true

        } else {
            isDarkMode = false
        }
    } else {
        isDarkMode = false
    }
}
```

`

please note also that the isDarkMode flag must be initialised somewhere in your code on the starting status of the device

```
        isDarkMode = (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark)
```

once you know that you are in dark mode you can probably redesign the UI to be with the colors you prefer.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use light map on dark mode. below example worked for me (Xcode v.10.3 - Swift 5)

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // using light map on dark mode
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        map.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
}
```